# REST endpoints that will server some JSON data

Tags: angularjs, json, web-services, rest

Are there any free hosted services where I can create a REST endpoint that will server some static JSON data. I basically want to call an asynchronouse web service from my sample angular project created in plunker?

Or

are there any free REST endpoints (without authentication) that I can hit and will serve some JSON data.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [what's on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what's not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Asking for recommendations or off-site resources is specifically off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this site to get REST api with json as a result.
[JsonPlaceHolder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)